# What happens to a changeling who (accidentally) drinks some blood of a True Fae?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, changeling-the-lost

I play in a *World of Darkness: Changeling the Lost* game and recently we had a True Fae try to come through. We found it in the hedge and destroyed it; my character struck the killing blow. Now how she did this was basically by leaping onto its back and tearing out its throat...with her teeth.

The ST I was playing under said I did not need to roll for clarity degeneration. My regular ST disagrees, so I will be doing a degeneration roll when I get home, but I feel like that is a little too small a punishment? I mean, she pretty much *drank* Fae blood.

My question is: **Is there a precedent for what should happen?** Failing that, a suggestion for something that may happen to my character, that I can in turn suggest to the ST, would be useful.

Comment: one negative consequence, you've really angered the True Fae, and it sends more Actor's (and traitors) after you, maybe it goes all in, this would give you a chance to really kill it. I don't think that's the answer you're looking for though, which is why I'm leaving it in a comment.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, from what I remember from [Equinox Road](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/57384/Equinox-Road), a True Fae itself isn't really what's coming through, rather one of its Actors. Killing an Actor is akin to destroying a True Fae title. When all of its titles are gone, so is it.

As far as consequences, I think a Degeneration role might be appropriate depending on your current Clarity level, probably with a bonus considering what it was.

In regards to the Blood itself, @MarkShovman is right about one thing: there are rules for Vampires consuming Fae/Changeling Vitae. However, you are not a Vampire. What happens when a person drinks blood? Depending on how much, you might get nausea or throw up. If your ST wanted to decide that the blood contained toxins maybe that comes into effect, but there's really nothing special about Actors that's different from Changelings in this particular regard.

Comment: +1 for basically  "Its just blood. Drinking blood is unhealthy, but it is in no way special (to anything other than a vampire) because it was part of an Actor."

Comment: a good point thanks i'll talk to my st, luckily i think she has avoided most of the toxin and things becouse of iron stomach and some other things i gave her so she could basicly be a hedgefruit tester. it was a title rather then a true fae in whole so it will be interestign.

Comment: @Kat worth noting that Changelings are unlikely to have any idea about Actor's/Title's, to them it's basically the same difference. They are, iirc, ignorant of just how "god like" the True Fae are.

Comment: since it was done in the Hedge, I am not sure how much the regular physiology of drinking blood applies.

Answer (score -4):

There are rules of drinking Fae blood, but they are for Vampires, and it's hardly the same. But essentially vampires gain derangements, one for each BP they drink.

Purely as a suggestion, I'd say your character now considers himself somewhat of a vampire, and their mien now comes with glowing red eyes and pointy fangs :)

Comment: I downvoted because "your player considers themselves a vampire" is BS. This scenario isn't any different from you getting another persons blood in your mouth. Maybe if you like the taste of the blood...

Comment: Changeling Mien is not affected by your own perception of what you are. Your Mien is affected basically only by what your keeper wanted you to be, and certain specialised entitlements. I guess a case could be made that by drinking a Keepers blood you have gained part of a Title and thus are now specially entitled, but that is a pretty big stretch.

Comment: To be fair that is pretty much her mien already she is a hunterheart with prominant fangs and goldern eyes.